# dreamweaver regex $1 escape in replace

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

i got this:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?>
```

and i have to change it in this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/(.*)([\d]{2})([^\d].*)?$/','$1<span class="cents">$2</span>$3',Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true)) ?>
```

using regex.
How to escape $1 in replace?

**EDIT**
Ok this question isn't clear.
I'm using Dreamweaver to manipulate a php file.
I've got many strings that ouput a formatted price.
I need to add a span tag to style the cents smaller than the rest.
To do that i need to wrap each string in a preg_replace() function.
All this stings i need to modify are different but got "formatPrice" in it.
So with Dreamweaver i'm goin to modify all this strings using regex in Find&Replace.
The new string contains **"$1"** and create a conflict with **$1 Dreamweaver backreference**, so i need a way to escape it.
The two strings above are in order an example of what i got and what should be after find and replace.

Comment: i tried and it write \$1 instead of $1

Comment: Try `$$1` in the replace, `$$` is used to insert `$`.

Comment: What is held in `echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true);`? What is the expected output? You do not need to escape $ in the replacement since that is a part of a replacement backreference.

Comment: This looks like a PHP question and you are just using Dreamweaver as the texteditor, is that correct?

Comment: @stribizhev the second string of code is the expected output: It's look confuse 'couse i need to insert a preg_replace() function in a php file, but to do that i need to use regex in dreamweaver

Comment: @Tushar what you suggest give me tha result: `<?php echo preg_replace('/(.*)([\d]{2})([^\d].*)?$/','$Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true)<span class="cents">$2</span>$3',Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true))?>` That is wrong

Comment: @chris85 you're correct

Comment: @stribizhev if you mean what is the php output is a price format like 800,25 € and i need to render cents smaller

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this:
as php use \1 as well as $1 as backreference i used this setting in dramweaver Find&Replace:

- Find:`([^\s]*formatPrice.*\));?\s`
- Replace:`preg_replace('/(.*)([\d]{2})([^\d].*)?$/','\1<span class="cents">\2</span>\3',$1)`

So i don't need to escape $1 anymore.
But still should be interesting find out if there is a way to use $1 in replace statment not as backreference

Comment: What was/is your original `find` and `replace` values?

Comment: @chris85 hi, this is not a php question but it is about find&replace dreamweaver regex. The php code is what i'm manipulating. The two stings of php code are in order what i've got and what should be after find&replace. Since i'm adding a preg_replace() function i needed to escape php backreference. Then i found this workaround.

Comment: In your question you have the original string, and the replacement value, what is the find value?

Comment: @chris85 I didn't think was necessary, it is the find in the answer `([^\s]*formatPrice.*\));?\s`

Comment: It looks like incorrect implementation of the escaped by Adobe. Using the backslash before the `$1` does make it literal but also places the escaping character in there. Another hacky approach you could use in this instance is non-capture groups `?:`.

Comment: @chris85 but it has to be a capture group

Comment: `preg_replace('/(.*)([\d]{2})([^\d].*)?$/','\1<span class="cents">\2</span>\3',$1)` tha last is the group as i have to wrap the function around it